# is it possible to define more than once aop:aspectj-autoproxy element

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have a root project which I can not change because it is a base project for other projects. It defines aop interceptors in spring configuration with aop:aspectj-autoproxy element.

I have another project which inherits the base project and needs to define its own interceptor with aop:aspectj-autoproxy, something like this:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy >
    <aop:include name="myInterceptor"/>
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
```

But I tested it and this is is not possible. Only the first configuration in the base project is taken into account and I can not move it or modify it.

How can I define my interceptor in this case? Can I merge somehow both configurations?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to add the include patterns, for example:

```
public class AspectJAutoProxyConfigurer implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private String[] includePatterns;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(
            ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

        BeanDefinition beanDef = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(AopConfigUtils.AUTO_PROXY_CREATOR_BEAN_NAME);
        ManagedList includes = (ManagedList) 
                beanDef.getPropertyValues().get("includePatterns");

        for (String includePattern : this.includePatterns)
            includes.add(new TypedStringValue(includePattern));

    }

    public String[] getIncludePatterns() {
        return includePatterns;
    }

    public void setIncludePatterns(String[] includePatterns) {
        this.includePatterns = includePatterns;
    }

}


<bean id="autoProxyCreatorConfigurer" class="AspectJAutoProxyConfigurer">
    <property name="includePatterns" value="one,two,three" />
</bean>
```